# Comparer<T> constructor

Tags: c#, .net, compare

Just out of curiosity I was looking at abstract Comparer(T) class source at [mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs), and it struck me the constructor is missing from the published source. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a stateless abstract class (i.e. it has no instance fields), it doesn't need a constructor because there is nothing to initialize.

It will, of course, have a default constructor which is compiler-generated, which any subclass constructor will call, but it will evaluate to call just the `Object` constructor (which in-turn doesn't really do much: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs )

Comment: So this MSDN doc should have pointed to Object constructor instead?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a42axckh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GBackMania: Why would it do that? What exactly do you mean by "pointed to"? It's not like the Object constructor is inherited - constructors are never inherited.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand. I was expecting to see a protected constructor in the published source as per MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a42axckh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GBackMania: Right - the constructor exists, but it's just autogenerated by the compiler because there are no *explicitly declared* constructors.

Comment: @JonSkeet that makes sense. how do you tell if it is autogenerated or explicitly declared from MSDN?

Comment: @GBackMania: Why would you care? The result will be identical to explicitly declaring the constructor with an empty body.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just curious :)